# Python wheel: same source code but different md5sum

Tags: python, md5sum, python-wheel

We need to check the md5sum of self made python packages, actually taking it from resulting `*.whl` file. The problem is that the md5sum changes on every build, even if there no changes in source code. Also we have tested this on third party packages, i.e. django-celery, and get the same behavior.

So the questions are:

1. What differs if we don't change the source code?
2. Is it possible to get the same md5sum for the same python builds?

upd.

To illustrate the issue I get two reports made on two django-celery builds.
Build content checksums is exactly the same (4th column), but the checksums of the *.whl files itself differs.

Links to the reports:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kkbhwd2fgopg67/django_celery-3.1.17-py2-none-any2.htm?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vecrq587jjrjh2r/django_celery-3.1.17-py2-none-any1.htm?dl=0

Comment: The checksums probably changes because timestamps are changing. But what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the relevant PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#abstract):

> A wheel is a ZIP-format archive with a specially formatted file name and the `.whl` extension.

ZIP archives preserve the modification time of each file.

Wheel archives do not contain just source code, but also [other files and directories](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-contents) that are generated on the fly when the archive is created. Therefore, even if you don't touch your Python source code, the wheel will still contain contents that have a different modification time.

---

One way to work around this problem is to unzip the wheel and compute the checksums of the contents.

Comment: Checksums of the contents are identical. Links to the reports added.

Comment: @some_user: that's the whole point of my answer. Compute the checksums of the contents instead of the archives.

Comment: its can not be accepted as a solution, since we need to take a checksums from wheel file itself.

Comment: @some_user: then build the wheel on a filesystem with no mtime support